# Check if specific role exists

Tags: user-roles

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a specific role exists. I found the following code on the web but it doesn't work for me:

```
function role_exists( $role ) {
    if ( ! empty( $role ) ) {
        return $GLOBALS['wp_roles']->is_role( $role );
    }

    return false;
}
```

I get the following error message: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_role() on null in C:\xampp...

I tried to output `$GLOBALS['wp_roles']` with a `print_r` but it's empty.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling this function? Is there any reason you're avoiding using the `is_role()` function which WordPress provides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on Bosco's comment. You can do this instead of line 3 in the above code:

```
wp_roles()->is_role( 'editor' );
```

That grabs a `WP_Roles` object (what the code you had tries to do by getting a global variable) and calls the same `is_role()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm calling the function below in my file to create a new role:

```
if ( ! ( role_exists( 'manager' ) ) ) {
    function new_role_manager() {
        global $wp_roles;

        if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) ) {
            $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
        }

        $adm = $wp_roles->get_role( 'administrator' );

        $wp_roles->add_role( 'manager', 'Gestionnaire', $adm->capabilities );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'new_role_manager' );
}
```

I fixed my problem using Nabha's solution. Here is the updated `role_exists()` function:

```
function role_exists( $role ) {
    if ( ! empty( $role ) ) {
        return wp_roles()->is_role( $role );
    }

    return false;
}
```

Many thanks.